# Datatransfer between activities (Application obj Vs Intent)

Tags: android

What is the best way to pass the objects from one activity to another? I came to know about 2 approaches:

1) setting data to Application obj, and then accessing the same application obj using getApplication in another activity

2) using puExtra methods of intent objects

Please let me know the best approach.

Thanks,
Venkat Papana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach is passing info through Intents using the putExtra which fills the bundle.

Storing info in the Application is bad practice and might bite you in the rear when you re-start your activities, or Android decides to kill/restore the activity.

Comment: Thank you Reflog, but when it is wise to use Application object?

Comment: Well, it is rather useful as a sort of Singleton to keep 'global' methods used in several activities in your application.